# Ruby Strings - Checking against a set of strings to match

Tags: ruby, arrays, filter

I am trying to check an array of strings for containing one or more matching strings.

Currently I am doing this by using if statements - not nice, but it works - However now I am looking for a more Ruby-like way to do this.

```
row[:datapoints].each do |data|             
    if data[:direction].include? "Beusselstr"
        data[:image] = "category-1"
    end     
    if data[:direction].include? "Ostkreuz"
        data[:image] = "category-1"
    end                         
    if data[:direction].include? "Westend"
        data[:image] = "category-2"
    end
    if data[:direction].include? "1)S Gr"
        data[:image] = "category-3"             
    end
end
```

Instead of this I'd like to store the matching strings in an array. To make it a bit more complicated I actually have different categories of matching terms with their own result actions (see category specific assignment of the data[:image] value).

```
category_1_keywords = ["Beusselstr","Ostkreuz"]
category_2_keywords = ["nefeld Bhf","Greifswalder","Westend"]
category_3_keywords = ["1)S Gr"]

imagecategories = {:category_1 => category_1_keywords,:category_2 => category_2_keywords,:category_3 => category_3_keywords}
```

How would filtering the array (**row[:datapoints]**) using such a matching array (**imagecategories**) look like?

Comment: last part is not clear like `category_1_keywords`,`category_2_keywords` etc.

Comment: Basically I'd like to use an array (imagecategories) containing arrays with category specific keywords/matching terms (category_..._keywords). I am a beginner with Ruby. Maybe there's a better way to construct the search object structure containing the terms and categories.

Comment: what is your final goal,give some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use the array intersection operator `&` and check if it's empty.

```
if (data[:direction] & category_1_keywords).any?
  data[:image] = "category-1"
end
```

4 if's in a row though start looking like time for an iterator:

```
keywords = {
'category_1' => ["Beusselstr","Ostkreuz"],
'category_2' => ["nefeld Bhf","Greifswalder","Westend"],
'category_3' => ["1)S Gr"]
}

data[:image] = keywords.find{|k,v| (data[:direction] & v).any?}[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the right direction. However the strings should also match if the matching string is only a part of the string. Not necessarily a full match. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `data[:direction]` is a string, you can find the category with:

```
data[:image], _ = imagecategories.find { |category, keywords|
  keywords.any? { |keyword|
    data[:direction].include?(keyword)
  }
}
```

In plain text: find the first category-keywords pair (`imagecategories.find`) having any keyword (`keywords.any?`) that the `data[:direction]` string contains.